# Constant overload not working

Tags: typescript, constants, overloading

The following very simple code outputs an error saying that 'Object does not have a sayHello method'. Why doesn't TypeScript detect testModule has the TestModule type?

```
interface TestModule extends Object { sayHello(); }
interface ModuleHub {
    (file: string): Object;
    (file: 'test-module'): TestModule;
}

var require: ModuleHub;
var testModule = require('test-module');
testModule.sayHello();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload order is significant. You need the string argument overload before the generic one:

```
interface TestModule extends Object { sayHello(); }
interface ModuleHub {
    (file: 'test-module'): TestModule; // Before
    (file: string): Object;            // Generic last as a catchall
}

var require: ModuleHub;
var testModule = require('test-module');
testModule.sayHello();
```

Comment: Thanks. I also figured out that you can do this instead:

    interface ModuleHub { (file: string): Object; }
    interface ModuleHub { (file: 'test-module'): TestModule; }

Not sure why, though.